# Method of an object in Python

Tags: python, object, methods

I was just pulling off a toy example for myself, but it is not working and I cannot make it work. Does anybody know why this is not working and how to make it work:

```
class A(object):
    #def __init__():
        #pass
    def do1():
        print("foo")
        def do2():
            print("Hello")

Al = A 
Al.do1()
```

TypeError: unbound method do1() must be called with A instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

Comment: `Al = A() <- parens`

Comment: Thanks! That solves the issue

Comment: What are you trying to do with the rest of the code?

Comment: I need to call the second method of that object from outside the object, but I don't know how to do that because it's inside another method.

Comment: Do you have any idea, by accident?

Comment: No worries, I'll make it into another post since it's a different question

Comment: Are you actually trying to create a wrapper?

Comment: This is one way http://pastebin.com/f7tApLKg

Comment: Thanks. However, I need it to only carry out 'do2', is that also possible? So then it would just print 'Hello' and nothing else.

Comment: Are you sure you are supposed to have the function nested inside do1? Maybe http://pastebin.com/YCXfK1AM?

Comment: Yeah I'm actually using someone else's code. I'm pretty sure that he uses the nested definition, as in, he uses do2 within do1. But now I want to call do2 outside of the object.

Comment: Unless you have to do it that way then just use the code above making it a separate method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call your class to crate a correct instance and pass the `self` keyword to enclosing function to provides a handle back to the instance to be processed :

```
class A(object):
    #def __init__():
        #pass
    def do1(self):
        print("foo")
        def do2():
            print("Hello")

Al = A()
Al.do1()
```

Note that without passing the `self` to your function after calling it you will get a `TypeError`.

```
TypeError: do1() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Or as @Padraic Cunningham mentioned in comment you can use [`staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod) as a decorator to wrap your function which makes python doesn't pass the first default argument (self) to it.

```
class A(object):
    #def __init__():
        #pass
    @staticmethod
    def do1():
        print("foo")
        def do2():
            print("Hello")

Al = A()
Al.do1()
```

Comment: You don't actually need self if it were actually a static method

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yep, updated the question, thanks for attention!

Answer (score 4):

In your code variable A1 it's reference to your class not instance, create instance of your class

```
Al = A()
```

and run your method

```
Al.do1()
```